# Is Wordpress "publish" atomic?

Tags: publish

If it is atomic, this must be a bug.

What I have noticed is that, when a post is being published and I close the window, the post gets published partially - one time only body came but not the subject. Is this supposed to happen?

I am not using wordpress client, but using it online to post on a blog.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not.

Publishing post is just a form submit and series of PHP function calls. When you close browser window that is treated according to [PHP connection handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) rules and settings. So if script terminates early the publishing process won't be complete or rolled back to start either.

Comment: Thanks, but too bad, I think this definitely should be an enhancement.